# Error running Serverless Framework command after upgrading to v3

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I recently upgraded my Serverless Framework project from `v2.7` to `v3.0.1`. After doing so, any time I run `serverless deploy` I get the following error:

```
Environment: win32, node 14.18.1, framework 3.0.1, plugin 6.0.0, SDK 4.3.0
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
TypeError: validate is not a function
    at ConfigSchemaHandler.validateConfig (C:\Users\MainPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\config-schema-handler\index.js:101:5)
    at async Service.validate (C:\Users\MainPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\service.js:267:5)
    at async Serverless.run (C:\Users\MainPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\serverless\lib\serverless.js:162:28)
    at async C:\Users\MainPC\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\serverless\scripts\serverless.js:675:9
```

I have tried the following:

- Creating a new "hello world" project by running `serverless` and selecting the NodeJS starter project
- Uninstalling `nvm` and re-installing NodeJS v14.18.1 completely
- Deleted every globally installed NPM module and re-installed *only* SLS from scratch

I am now running standalone v14 Node without NVM (on Windows 10) and still the error persists. Reverting to v2.7 resolves the error.

Nobody else seems to be suffering this issue. Can anyone offer some assistance?

---

For those asking for the template, the error even happens on this demo template that Serverless itself generates for a new project:

```
service: testing-v3

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
```

I am pretty confident the issue is either an installation issue or something specific to v3, or both.

Comment: Could you share your serverless.yml as that directly impacts the error you are seeing?

Comment: @GarethMcCumskey I will post this evening but it's happening even on the basic NodeJS starter project that you can create by running `serverless` in an empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some rules to upgrade your versions to v3, Serverless Framework v3 contains breaking changes that may impact projects.
In my opinion will be impacted a lot of projects.
some of the issues are:

- frameworkVersion: '3'

---

## CLI Commands

### Will no longer work in v3:

```
serverless --verbose deploy
```

### Correct syntax:

```
serverless deploy --verbose
```

---

## Service configuration

### Deprecated in v2, removed in v3:

```
service:
    name: my-service
```

### Correct syntax:

```
service: my-service
```

---

I really recommend you to check this
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/upgrading-v3
has the full guide to support the issues you may have.

Comment: Thanks Will, I have actually gone through that document pretty extensively. As I explained to another commenter, the issue persists even when I use the basic NodeJS starter project that Serverless itself generates when you run `serverless` in an empty directory, so I assume v3 of SLS isn't going to generate templates that it cannot run. I'm convinced the issue is with my installation of SLS rather than anything in the template, but given that I've totally wiped NodeJS / npm from my machine and re-installed I cannot see what else I can do.